# Error when trying to update Craft or install any plugin

Tags: plugins, redactor, installation, composer

When I try to update Craft, or install any plugin from the plugin store, I get the following error):

```
Composer was unable to install the updates.

Error: The url supplied for the path (plugins/redactor) repository does not exist

Composer output: Package "craftcms/vue-asset" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

If I try installing a plugin through the command line, I get a similar error:

```
 [RuntimeException]
 The 'url' supplied for the path (plugins/redactor) repository does not exist
```

Here are the contents of my composer.json file:

```
{
  "require": {
  "craftcms/cms": "3.5.2",
  "craftcms/contact-form": "2.2.7",
  "craftcms/feed-me": "4.2.3",
  "craftcms/redactor": "2.6.1",
  "craftcms/simple-text": "2.0.2",
  "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.4.0"
},
  "require-dev": {
  "yiisoft/yii2-shell": "^2.0.3"
},
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
    "modules\\": "modules/"
   }
},
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "platform": {
    "php": "7.0"
  }
},
"scripts": {
  "post-root-package-install": [
    "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
  ]
},
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "plugins/redactor"
    }
  ]
}
```

The redactor plugin is already installed and working properly, so I'm not sure why it's causing an issue. Does anyone know what's causing this issue and how to fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the contents of your composer.json file?

Comment: Edited. Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "plugins/redactor"
    }
  ]
```

With that in your composer.json file, you're telling Composer to look in a `plugins/redactor` folder from the root of your project and use that to satisfy the `"craftcms/redactor"` dependency (instead of pulling it from packagist.org).

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

That error is saying that the `plugins/redactor` folder doesn't exist. The most common use-case for that is you've got a separate fork of the plugin you're using, but if that's not the case, you can remove that whole `repositories` section and it'll start using the official redactor release from packagist.

Comment: That was it. I removed the repositories section and was able to update Craft, a few existing plugins, and install a new plugin I had been unable to install.  Thank you for your help.